# Strange Maven nullpointer

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3, executable-jar, artifact

**I have modified this question since initially asking it. Please refer to sections UPDATE 1 and, specifically, UPDATE 2 at the end.**

I am building a large JavaFX application with a lot of dependencies. I am using IntelliJ to do the job and am at the point of deployment. I am using IntelliJ's own tutorial on artifacts to build an executable jar. The tutorial can be seen in the ["Working with artifacts" tutorial on jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html).

I have built my executable jar and it is working as it should, with one caveat, however:

I have to manually mimic the directory structure of my IntelliJ project for the executable jar file to find the resources necessary for the program to function properly.

This is where my question comes in: shouldn't IntelliJ include these files in the artifact, so it can run in and on its own?

My directory structure in IntelliJ looks like this:

```
Project root
  .idea
  .out
  .src
    .main
      .java
        .com
          .myCompany
            .package-with-classes1
              .class1 ... N
            .package-with-classes2
              .class1 ... N
                .package-with-files
                  .file1.someExtension
                  .file2.someExtension
            .other-package-classes
            .and-so-on
```

When I build the artifact under Project Structure - Artifacts - Output Layout, I then manually add the directory structure as can be seen above, and then place the files where they belong.

As per my question above, I would expect these files to be automatically included with the executable jar file.

**UPDATE 1: Added Maven to project**

Due to [Andrey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872291/intellij-artifact-doesnt-mimic-directory-structure?noredirect=1#comment86770528_49872291) I have now implemented Maven in my project. I have *a lot* of external dependencies which I have added to my pom.xml file like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}\path\to\jar\jarfile.jar</systemPath
</dependency>
```

I then do:

1. mvn clean
2. mvn compile
3. mvn package

All runs with no errors.

It places 2 jar files in my \target folder: (1) name-of-jar.jar and (2) name-of-jar-with-dependencies.jar.

Running (1) throws the error: no main manifest attribute. Running (2) throws ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError errors. Why is this? The classes throwing the errors *are* included as dependencies using the above approach.

**UPDATE 2: Progress with Maven, but...**

I solved the issue in section *UPDATE 1* by installing all my third party jar libraries to my local machine's Maven repository at C:\Users\$USER$.m2\repository. However, getting a null pointer...

I changed my dependency declarations in my pom.xml to the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>some.version.number</version>
</dependency>
```

I am currently building my fat jar using the maven assembly plugin (I have also tried using the shade plugin but am having the same issue). Here's the excerpt of the assembly plugin from my pom.xml:

```
 <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
         <archive>
             <manifest>
                 <mainClass>com.myCompany.myMainClass</mainClass>
             </manifest>
         </archive>
         <descriptorRefs>
             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
         </descriptorRefs>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>make-assembly</id>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>single</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

This produces the same two jar files in the \target directory as described in section *UPDATE 1*.

Now, if I run `jar -tf name-of-jar-with-dependencies.jar` I can see from the directory contents of this jar that the jar in fact does contain all the third party jar libraries that was missing; and running the jar file using `java -jar name-of-jar-with-dependencies.jar` does not throw the errors as described in section *UPDATE 1* any longer. So far, so good.

However, it does throw a NullPointerException which puzzles me. Specifically, it is complaining that the a certain class is missing. This seems a little strange to me since this class is part of a third party jar library which I *did* add as a dependency in my pom.xml. The fact that this class is indeed included in the final jar was confirmed by the approach above, printing out the contents of the name-of-jar-with-dependencies.jar, which - among a lot of other files - includes this very jar file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Very well written first question buddy. Well done!

Comment: I am pretty sure IntelliJ should allow you to explictly state which resources are included in your deployed artifact. Does the guide you linked in your question not instruct you on such a process?

Comment: @RannLifshitz Not sure if you're being sarcastic or not but...thanks. I will go over the tutorial once again.

Comment: I am never sarcastic with new SO users. There are enough harsh SO users here who are into behaving in such a manner and I personally hate that. I am honestly curious as to how you can package your resources via IntelliJ's deployment (I am more familiar with how Maven does this). I expect the guide to show how this is done, and this is not the case - it seems IntelliJ should update their guide.

Comment: @RannLifshitz In that case I apologize! Thank you for your help so far. Yeah it doesn't seem apparent in the tutorial but I will scoure it to make sure I haven't missed anything.

Comment: Cool, If you manage to find the answer - please post an answer to your own quesiton so that all of us will get to benefit from your research. Thanks in advance buddy!

Comment: What and how exactly do you copy in the artifact? Do you use Maven? If you do, does Maven build different artifact? e.e. note that Maven by default copies resources only from [standard](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) "src/main/resources" directory.

Comment: @Andrey I follow the approach as described by the tutorial to which I linked in my initial question. The approach is as follows (in IntelliJ IDEA): Project Structure - Artifacts - Add (Alt + Insert) - JAR - From module with dependencies. I add my main class and select "copy to the output directory and link via manifest." I choose this option because the option "extract to the target JAR" throws a missing manifest error when I try to run the .jar file via the command line using java -jar jarfile.

Comment: @Andrey I now added Maven to my project but are having some complications. Please refer to the section **UPDATE 1** above for details.